# Dynamically numbering files in R with placeholders using an If-elseif

Tags: r

I have a vector

```
x <- c(1,90,233)
```

I need to convert this to a vector of the form:

```
result = c("001.csv","090.csv","233.csv")
```

This is the function that I wrote to perform this operation:

```
convert <- function(x){
  for (a in 1:length(x)){
    if (x[a]<10) {
      x[a]<- paste("00",x[a],".csv",sep="")
    }
    else if (x[a] < 100) {
      x[a]<- paste("0", x[a], ".csv",sep="")
    }
   else {
      x[a]<-paste(x[a],".csv",sep="")
      }
  }
  x
}
```

The output I got was:

```
[1] "001.csv","90.csv","233.csv"
```

So, `a[2]` is `90` was processed in the `else` part and not the `else if` part. Then I changed the `else if` condition to `x[a]<=99`

```
convert <- function(x){
  for (a in 1:length(x)){
    if (x[a]<10) {
      x[a]<- paste("00",x[a],".csv",sep="")
    }
    else if (x[a] <= 99) {
      x[a]<- paste("0", x[a], ".csv",sep="")
    }
   else {
      x[a]<-paste(x[a],".csv",sep="")
      }
  }
  x
}
```

I got this output:

```
[1] "001.csv"  "090.csv"  "0233.csv"
```

Now both `x[2]` and `x[3]` ie 90 and 233 are being processed in the ElseIf part. What am I doing wrong here? And how do I get the output I need?

Comment: `sprintf("%03d.csv", x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the first round of your loop makes a character, that converts the whole vector to type character. You can get around that using `nchar`

```
convert <- function(x){
  for (a in 1:length(x)){
    if (nchar(x[a]) == 1) {
      x[a]<- paste("00",x[a],".csv",sep="")
    }
    else if (nchar(x[a]) == 2) {
      x[a]<- paste("0", x[a], ".csv",sep="")
    }
    else {
      x[a]<-paste(x[a],".csv",sep="")
    }
  }
  x
}
```

Comment: or you can create a new vector `y` and paste into that vector

Comment: Got it! Though still not clear about how <100 made a difference from <=99

Comment: @SB3891 try `as.character(90) < 99`, for some reason it gives true while for some reason `as.character(90) < 100` gives false

Answer (score 5):

This is a little bit more dynamic as you do not need to specify the number of places held by the largest number.

**Step 1:**

Obtain the maximum number of places held.

```
(nb = max(nchar(x)))
```

To get:

```
3
```

**Step 2:**

Paste the number into a `sprintf()` call that will automatically format the digit.

```
sprintf("%0*d.csv", nb, x)
```

To get:

```
[1] "001.csv" "090.csv" "233.csv"
```

Comment: `sprintf("%0*d.csv", nb, x)`

Comment: Nice! didn't realize you could use a `*`! Updated my answer to get rid of the `paste()` function.

Answer (score 4):

```
sprintf("%03d", x)
[1] "001" "090" "233"
```

You can avoid a call to `paste` by including the ".csv" in the format string:

```
sprintf("%03d.csv", x)
[1] "001.csv" "090.csv" "233.csv"
```

The problem with the original code is the conversion to character, which happens on the first element.

Here's the conversion to character:

```
> x <- c(1, 90, 233)
> x
[1]   1  90 233
> x[1] <- "001.csv"
> x
[1] "001.csv" "90"    "233"
```

Here's the resulting comparison of the second element:

```
> "90" <= 99
[1] TRUE
> "90" < 100
[1] FALSE
```

Similarly for the third:

```
> "233" < 100
[1] FALSE
> "233" <= 99
[1] TRUE
```

In all of these cases, the right-hand side is converted to character, then the comparison is made, as character strings.

Comment: Great minds and all that... ;-) - You can also bung the ".csv" in there `sprintf("%03d.csv", x)`

Comment: Especially for those of us whose first language is C.  Indeed, adding the ".csv" in the `sprintf` is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work as expected because the whole vector gets converted into a character vector after first assignment(conversion of numeric to character).

Please note that when a string is compared to digit, the characters are matched one by one. For eg. if you compare "90" to 100 then 9 is compared to 1, hence control goes to the else part and in the case of comparison of "233" to 99, 2 is compared 9.

You can get around this by assigning the changed values to another vector.Or, you could use the str_pad function from the stringr package.

```
library(stringr)

x=c(1,90,233)

padded_name= str_pad(x,width=3,side="left",pad="0")
file_name = paste0(padded_name, ".csv")
```

Comment: Didn't know that strings get compared character by character! That did clear it up for me! Thanks!